# multiple divs + javascript + cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, setcookie

I'm trying to make a showHide persistant across page loads by setting a cookie. My problem is that I have more than one div to account for. How can this be done? I've tried using the or operator, i.e.:

```
var closed = $(".Div1").is(":hidden") || $(".Div2").is(":hidden");
        if (closed)
            $(".Div1").show() || $(".Div2").show();
        else
            $(".Div1").hide(); || $(".Div2").hide();
    ...etc...
```

...but had no luck.  Here is how I made it work with a single div (Div1):

```
$( window ).load(function () {
    $(".showHide").on("click", function () {
        var closed = $(".Div1").is(":hidden");
        if (closed)
            $(".Div1").show();
        else
            $(".Div1").hide();

        setCookie("open", closed, 365);
    });

    var openToggle = getCookie("open");    
    if (openToggle=="true") {        
        $(".Div1").show();
    }
    else {        
        $(".Div1").hide();
    }

});

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for helping out.

I think its getting close. I set `<div class="Div1">` but I still cannot get each div to open (or fadeIn) independently. Do you think it might have something to do with `var openToggle` ? Thank you. :-)

UPDATED CODE ~ 2:45pm GMT

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    $(".showHide").on("click", function() {
    $("div[class='Div1']").each(function(i,op) {
    $("div[class='Div1']").fadeOut(1);
    $("div[class='Div1']").eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(1000);
    setCookie("open_" + i, closed, 365);
    });
});
    $("div[class='Div1']").each(function(i,op)
   {
    var openToggle = getCookie("open_" + i);    
    if (openToggle=="true") {        
    $(this).show();
}
else {        
    $(this).hide();
}
});
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple divs , you need to iterate through each one and check which ones are hidden and then show them. Also, you need to save and extract each cookie uniquely, so i made use of index of each div and appended it to cookie name.

Provided .Div is a class applied to DIV elements.

```
 $(".showHide").on("click", function () {
          $(".Div1").each(function(i,op)
          {
              var closed  = $(this).is(":hidden");
              if(closed)
                 $(this).show();
              else 
                 $(this).hide();

             setCookie("open_" + i, closed, 365);
          });
    });

    $(".Div1").each(function(i,op)
   {
    var openToggle = getCookie("open_" + i);    
if (openToggle=="true") {        
    $(this).show();
}
else {        
    $(this).hide();
}
});
```

UPDATED : if div1 class is applied to other elements,

```
 $(".showHide").on("click", function () {
          $("div[class='Div1']").each(function(i,op)
          {
              var closed  = $(this).is(":hidden");
              if(closed)
                 $(this).show();
              else 
                 $(this).hide();

         setCookie("open_" + i, closed, 365);
      });
});

$("div[class='Div1']").each(function(i,op)
   {
    var openToggle = getCookie("open_" + i);    
if (openToggle=="true") {        
    $(this).show();
}
else {        
    $(this).hide();
}
});
```

Comment: Hmm, still no luck. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: oops. forgot to put the underscore character for getCookie. Fixed the code.

Comment: Would it matter if class="Div1" is applied to a `<td>` ? I ask because the initial click is revealing every Div1 on the page. I only want one at a time. Thanks again.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the div1 class only applicable to div elements, but if you wish to use it with other elements, you need to target only div with class div1. I've updated that section of the code.